# Monitor server requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 web application. To get data from third party, my application makes several HTTP requests from server. I want to see all the http requests made to the third party  from server for each page loads. I have installed glimpse from nu-get package. but I could not see any remote HTTP calls made from server. I am debugging my application in my local machine. is it possible to get this information using glimpse? if not is there any other tool can help me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Glimpse does not currently show HTTP requests your application has made - but that sounds like a great feature!

You do have a few options:

1. [Create a custom tab using Glimpse's extensibility model](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/wiki/Extending). You could tap into whatever HTTP client you are using and expose the data.
2. Additionally, you could leverage [Glimpse's Trace Tab](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Trace-Tab) to trace out messages about your HTTP requests.
3. Finally, you could use [ANTS Performance Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/features/key-features) which recently added a feature to see all the HTTP requests an application makes, in addition to CPU level timing information and SQL queries. ([And it has a free trial](https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/download)!)

Comment: thanks for your answer! version 8 http://www.red-gate.com/labs/ants-performance-profiler/ has this feature!